# Where are gdb breakpoints saved?

Tags: debugging, command-line, gdb, breakpoints, gnu

Suppose I add a bunch of breakpoints and do `save breakpoints filename`, now gdb saves this information in a file called `filename` and allows me to load these breakpoints in another instance of gdb using `source breakpoints filename`. Could you please tell me where is the file saved?

The reason I ask is because I saved my breakpoints a couple of days ago, and now I can't remember what filename I had used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where is the file saved?

If you didn't give it full pathname, the file would be saved in your current directory.

> I can't remember what filename I had used.

`man find` may come handy. If you generally work in subdirectories of your `$HOME`, then `find $HOME -type f -mtime -5` will find all files modified in the last 5 days.